# Be able to pull from git without password on login or just run keychain which does it for me

Tags: ssh, bash, git, ssh-agent, keychain

I need to pull from Github all the time and I have a passphrase, but it's a pain, so I typically run...

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
<prompt and give passphrase>
git pull
...
```

And that works for the session, but even after I logout, I would like it to save the passphrase next time I PuTTY in.  So I installed keychain, but I'm too dumb to operate it.  So now when I login, I type...

```
ssh-agent bash (Which I'm guessing causes bashrc to load and then keychain loads)
git pull
...
```

How would I make it so I don't need to call "ssh-agent bash" every time I login?

I'm using ArchLinux...

Comment: Which platform are you doing this on? What is 'keychain'? Is it OS X's  Keychain?

Comment: This howto describes what you're trying to do: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is the best I could come up with...

Install keychain...

Then add the following to **~/.bashrc** file:

```
eval `keychain --eval id_rsa`
```

THEN add the following to **~/.bash_profile**:

```
ssh-agent bash
```

That will start keychain.  It isn't as simple as just putting both in the bash profile or bashrc file.

Answer (score 1):

Use Putty's ssh agent - Pageant  for your private keys and enable agent forwarding.
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter9.html